# Dart/Flutter static analysis behaves differently in two different projects (IntelliJ)

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea, static-analysis

I work on two different Flutter projects. One seems to have more strict checks than the other. How do I get the weaker-checks project to be as strict at the other? I tried adding `analysis_options.yaml` file together with installing `analyzer` and `flutter_lints` packages, but it does not seem to bring the expected results.

Project with "weaker" static analysis:
[image: Weaker check]

Project with "stronger" static analysis:
[image: Stronger check]

Comment: Do you have the same `sdk` version inside `pubspec.yaml` under `environment`?

Comment: Show your `pubspec.yaml` and `analysis_options.yaml` files.  Are both projects using the same versions of `flutter_lints`?  Do both projects explicitly *include* `flutter_lints`'s lint configuration (it's not sufficient to just add `flutter_lints` as a dependency)?

Comment: @julemand101 you're right, that was the difference. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently changing the SDK version in `pubspec.yaml` gave the desired result.
So apparently changing:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.10.0 <3.3.0"
```

to

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.18.0 <3.3.0"
```

results in much more strict static analyzer.

Dart language evolution page describes changes in subsequent versions:
https://dart.dev/guides/language/evolution